# Continuous maps between Banach spaces are smooth

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I was reading the folowing text about proving certain map between Banach spaces is smooth. [image]

The group under consideration is the gauge group (howver I do not think it is essential here). We are trying to prove that the multiplication is smooth, while it is continuous by Sobolev multiplication theorem, I wonder how we then get the smoothness of the map?

p.s. I'm not quite familiar with Sobolev theory so I apologize if that is a stupid question.